# How many $4$-digit positive integers with units digit $7$ have an odd digit sum?

Tags: combinatorics

Consider all the different $4$ digit numbers ending with $7$.
From these numbers, if we sum their digits, which ones will give an odd number?

I obtained $250$ possible combinations from:
$5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 1 + 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 1$, but the solutions have $216$ possible combinations. Where did I mess up ?

Thank you.

Comment: They probably don't want you to start with $0$, so the first $5$ should be a $4$ (if you have all even digits, you can only lead with $2,4,6,8$). That said, I'm not sure this is right anyway. Are you sure that that's what the problem is asking?

Comment: even if i star with four(which is correct, i forgot) it still doesnt output 216 @KevinLong

Comment: Unless I misunderstand something, this should be $9*10*5=450$. You can lead with any nonzero digit, then follow with any digit, and then the third digit is either even or odd based on the parity of the first two. By "different" $4$ digit number, did you mean such numbers that never repeat the same digit?

Comment: i think you forgot that the last digit is always 7 ? @KevinLong

Comment: What makes you say that?

Comment: Let's try discussing this in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65935/simple-combinatorics-question).

Comment: nevermind, i read what you said in a different way @KevinLong

Comment: If you are counting $4$-digit numbers with units digit $7$ that have an odd digit sum, then there are $450$ such numbers, as @KevinLong stated.  That said, it would help if we could see the exact wording of the question.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig We figured out in chat that you get $216$ if you assume the digits are all distinct, so the question wasn't phrased clearly.

Comment: The question should be restated to indicate that the digits are distinct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the digits are not distinct, there are $9*10*5=450$ possible numbers. There are $9$ choices for the first digit $a$ (any digit besides $0$), and $10$ choices for the second digit $b$ (any digit). The parity restriction need only affect the last digit we choose. If $a+b+7$ is odd, the third digit $c$ needs to be even, so we have $5$ choices for $c$. If $a+b+7$ is even, the third digit $c$ needs to be odd, so we again have only $5$ choices for $c$. That means we have $9*10*5$ choices total.

Hence, as the question is worded $216$ is not correct. However, it will work if we also assume that the digits must all be distinct. If this is the case, the counting method we tried in the last method won't work so easily (try it yourself to see why). Instead, we'll handle this case by case based on parity of the digits. For the sum of all four digits to be odd, we'll either have to pick three even digits ($EEE$), or one even digit and two odd digits. The latter case splits into three cases: $EOO$, $OEO$, and $OOE$, where the order of the letters designates the order of the digits, e.g. $EOO$ is $E$ as the first digit.

- To count $EEE$, the first digit $a$ can be any even digit except $0$, the second digit $b$ can be any even digit except $a$, and the third digit $c$ can be any even digit except $a$ or $b$. This gives $4*4*3=48$ possibilities.
- To count $EOO$, the first digit $a$ can be any even digit except $0$, the second digit $b$ can be any odd digit except $7$, and the third digit $c$ can be any odd digit except for $7$ or $b$. This gives $4*4*3=48$ possibilities.
- To count $OEO$, the first digit $a$ can be any odd digit except $7$, the second digit $b$ can be any even digit, and the third digit $c$ can be any odd digit except for $7$ or $a$. This gives $4*5*3=60$ possibilities.
- To count $OOE$, the first digit $a$ can be any odd digit except $7$, the second digit $b$ can be any odd digit except for $7$ or $a$, and the third digit $c$ can be any even digit. This gives $4*3*5=60$ possibilities.

Summing all four cases gives $48+48+60+60=216$.